# Authorization in Graphene Django

Tags: python, django, graphql, authorization

I am creating an API using Django and GraphQL (graphene django). To authenticate users, I use JWT (https://django-graphql-jwt.domake.io/en/latest/). Next, I am also using Relay.

Now, what is the best way to handle permissions in queries and mutations? Let's say I have two models (`Products` and `Transactions`). Regular users can do both queries and mutations on `products`. `Transactions` however should be restricted and only be accessible by admins/staff.

On the Graphene Django web pages (https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/authorization/) they (amongst others) discuss the following two options:

1. `def get_queryset(cls, queryset, info)` - Is it OK to check for authorization here (by using:

```
if info.context.user.is_anonymous:
    raise GraphQLError('You do not have permission to access this information')
return queryset
```

)? And for mutations, we could do a similar thing in `mutate_and_get_payload`.

2. use the LoginRequiredMixin - This blocks off the whole API. I only want to block of parts of the API.

Comment: were you able to get it done?